# Including scripts in index.jade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pug, video.js

I want to include scripts for js file in my index.jade file. Currently I added them but things doesn't seem to reflect on UI. I added markers.js script which is locally stored in my directory. This is my project structure

[image]

And here is my index.jade file's head_script section

```
block head_scripts
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")
    script(src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.3.0/video.js')
    link(href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.3.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet")
    script(src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.0/videojs-ie8.min.js')
    script(src='../client/pages/VideoScreen/markers.js')
    link(href='../client/pages/VideoScreen/marker.css' rel="stylesheet")
```

This is my server file

```
var debug  = require('debug')('tessact:node');
var app = express();


const IS_PROD = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");
const PORT = (process.env.PORT || 4200);

var routes = require('./routes').default;

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
}
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.set('env', IS_PROD ? 'production' : 'development');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compression());
app.use('/public', express.static(
  path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
));

app.use('/', routes());
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers


// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}


// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

const runServer = (app)=> {
  app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    debug(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`); 
    if (__DEV__)
      debug(`HMR on http://localhost:${config.BS_PORT}`);
  });  
}


runServer(app);

module.exports =
```

app;

Are the paths I added are correct? I included the scripts but markers are not showing up at all. This means that code is not using markers.js script. Can anyone please suggest me a solution?

Comment: The paths should be given from the browser's perspective, as URL paths for it to request as it loads the page. So, the answer depends on how your server is configured to serve client files like `marker.js` and `marker.css` rather than your project structure.

Comment: Please look at the updates @JonathanLonowski

Comment: The server doesn't appear to know anything about the `client` directory where the `marker.*` files exist. The `express.static()` middleware knows about the `public` directory, though. Does the project use any build tools to copy (and possibly combine or compress) files from `client` into `public`?

Comment: I did move markers.js in public folder. Then I changed src='/markers.js' . This  didn't work. Anything wrong in this?

Comment: The middleware is setup for paths starting with `/public` (via the 1st argument to `app.use()`), so try `src="/public/marker.js"`.

Comment: This worked. But is there any way I can keep the files in my earlier path only and make this woirk?

Comment: The app can use as many `express.static()` middlewares as desired, so you can add a 2nd that serves up the `client` directory (or a particular sub-directory of it). Otherwise, the file will have to exist in both directories. (And, using two directories can be useful with build tools. You can keep the original, human-friendly copy in one directory and output the result of the build to the other for serving.)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot